# Pip install flash-attn --no-build-isolation throwing error

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda

I am currently trying to install Apple's Ferret computer vision model and following the documentation provided [here](https://github.com/apple/ml-ferret/blob/main/README.md) on its github page. When running `pip install flash-attn --no-build-isolation` I am thrown this error:

```
  Collecting flash-attn
  Using cached flash_attn-2.5.0.tar.gz (2.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      /private/var/folders/q4/6n8875qj00l8ct6c5ms6y7dw0000gn/T/pip-install-cbzesfg4/flash-attn_07733c481d0948b3a44285f30d59fa03/setup.py:78: UserWarning: flash_attn was requested, but nvcc was not found.  Are you sure your environment has nvcc available?  If you're installing within a container from https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch, only images whose names contain 'devel' will provide nvcc.
        warnings.warn(
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/q4/6n8875qj00l8ct6c5ms6y7dw0000gn/T/pip-install-cbzesfg4/flash-attn_07733c481d0948b3a44285f30d59fa03/setup.py", line 133, in <module>
          CUDAExtension(
        File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1076, in CUDAExtension
          library_dirs += library_paths(cuda=True)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1203, in library_paths
          if (not os.path.exists(_join_cuda_home(lib_dir)) and
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 2416, in _join_cuda_home
          raise OSError('CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. '
      OSError: CUDA_HOME environment variable is not set. Please set it to your CUDA install root.
      
      
      torch.__version__  = 2.1.2
      
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Is it an issue with my anaconda environment i have set up for ferret? I tried running this using the MAX_JOBS==1 flag to mitigate run issues but that only produced the same result. Also tried running it with a specified version of flash-attn but it produced the same result as before. If my computer's specs are an issue I am running this on a Macbook Pro 2016 with an Intel Iris Graphics 550 1536 MB GPU and 2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5 CPU with 8Gb of RAM using MacOS.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: 1) The error is triggered because  you have not set CUDA_HOME environment variable 2) Even if you set that, you most likely wont be able to build or run that because CUDA can run only on NVidia GPU's.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your computer specs are an issue because [flash-attn is compatible with Unix operating System](https://pypi.org/project/flash-attn/) and not your Macbook Pro 2016.